# Unity 3D - Too many errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Two scripts are generating these errors by the looks of it, they are listed below:

**-------------------------------**
**GameInformation -  Coding listed below:**
**-------------------------------**

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class GameInformation : MonoBehaviour {

```
void Awake(){
    DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
}

public static string PlayerName{ get; set; }
public static int PlayerLevel{ get; set; }
public static BaseCharacterClass PlayerClass{ get; set; }
public static int Speed{ get; set; }
public static int Endurance{ get; set; }
public static int Strength{ get; set; }
public static int Health{ get; set; }
}
```

**-------------------------------**
 **The other script is SaveInformation:**
**-------------------------------**

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class SaveInformation {

```
public static void SaveAllInformation(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PLAYERLEVEL", GameInformation.PlayerLevel);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("PLAYERNAME", GameInformation.PlayerName);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("SPEED", GameInformation.Speed);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("ENDURANCE", GameInformation.Endurance);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("STRENGTH", GameInformation.Strength);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("HEALTH", GameInformation.Health);
    }
```

}

**-------------------------------**
**Errors :**
**-------------------------------**

> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(7,67): error
>   CS0117: `GameInformation' does not contain a definition for`
>   PlayerLevel'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(7,29): error
>   CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string, int)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(7,29): error
>   CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`object' expression to type `int'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(8,69): error
>   CS0117: `GameInformation' does not contain a definition for`
>   PlayerName'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(8,29): error
>   CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`object' expression to type
>   `string'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(9,64): error
>   CS0117: `GameInformation' does not contain a definition for`Speed'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(9,29): error
>   CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString(string, string)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(9,29): error
>   CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`object' expression to type
>   `string'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(10,68): error
>   CS0117: `GameInformation' does not contain a definition for`
>   Endurance'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(10,29): error
>   CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString(string, string)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(10,29): error
>   CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`object' expression to type
>   `string'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(11,67): error
>   CS0117: `GameInformation' does not contain a definition for`Strength'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(11,29): error
>   CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString(string, string)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(11,29): error
>   CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`object' expression to type
>   `string'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(12,65): error
>   CS0117: `GameInformation' does not contain a definition for`Health'
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(12,29): error
>   CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString(string, string)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> Assets/Standard
>   Assets/Scripts/SavingAndLoading/SaveInformation.cs(12,29): error
>   CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert`object' expression to type
>   `string'

**-------------------------------**

**Please keep in mind when replying that I am rather new to coding. Thanks!**

**-------------------------------**

Answer (score 3):

In the world of programming these are very basic errors and you will find it much easier to progress if you understand them rather than just download scripts and hoping they all plug together.  Below I have described each error's cause to get you started:

```
GameInformation' does not contain a definition for
  PlayerLevel'
// This one means you're talking about PlayerLevel 
// in GameInformation, but GameInformation doesn't have PlayerLevel

The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetInt(string, int)' has some invalid arguments
// This means that you're trying to call SetInt with something that isn't a string
// or something that isn't an int

Argument #2' cannot convert object' expression to type `int'
// Same as above, trying to give *object* to something that expects *int*

GameInformation' does not contain a definition for
  PlayerName'
// GameInformation doesn't have PlayerName either

Argument #2' cannot convertobject' expression to type `string'
// Can't put an *object* Type into *string*

GameInformation' does not contain a definition forSpeed'
// You can probably guess that this means that there is no Speed in GameInformation

GameInformation' does not contain a definition for
 Endurance'
// You guessed it, no Endurance in GameInformation :)

The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs.SetString(string, string)' has some invalid arguments
// Based on the other errors, you're probably trying to pass *object* as
// a *string*
```

Basically, the errors all come down to one thing:  Your GameInformation class doesn't have the properties that you're referencing (Endurance, Speed, etc.) and this is upsetting the compiler.

Comment: As could be inferred from my answer either add the properties or remove the references to the properties that don't exist.  The second implication of my reply was that if you *can't* fix it, you *can* learn.  Here's a set of tutorials so you can actually learn how to program: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by add the properties!?

Comment: How or what to I do to add them!?